# When i change the background color of editText, the whole background color changes in android studio

Tags: android, xml

I am having isssue in changing the background color of the password in android studio and the issue is when i change the background color of the password field, the whole background color of the screen chages.
Before applying background color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#201953"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="Trip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="mat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Before adding background color to password field layout is below:

[image: Before adding background color to password field]

After applying background color to password field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#201953"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="Trip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="mat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#fff"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

After adding background color to the password field layout is below:

[image: After adding background color to the password field]

Comment: Your code is working fine in device.. test yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#201953" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#201953">

        <TextView
            android:text="Trip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="mat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it works fine but can you explain what was the issue.

Comment: You had given gravity center it is different from layout_gravity to edittext so. Mark my answer as answered Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

no need to take second `LinearLayout` for this, simply remove  `android:gravity="center"` from EditText as shown below. it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#201953"    
   android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="Trip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:text="mat"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edt_background"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

**edt_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#ffff" />
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:topRightRadius="1dp" />
</shape>
```

use `android:background="@drawable/edt_background"` with gravity as i updated whole code

Comment: why gravity does not work here. I also need to center the text inside the password field.

Comment: see updated answer as you want to use gravity inside password field. @HaroonKhan

Answer (score 0):

You can change background color by placing following code in java class wherever you need

```
  Edittext password;
  password.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.samplecolor));
  //here R.color.samplecolor is defined in colors.xml under values dir
```